# React Native fresh project breaks on any package install

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

I worked with React Native about a year ago, and since then many things have very apparently changed. Installing module used to be simple, but now I can't seem to install anything without completely breaking the project permanently. I create a new project under Expo XDE and title it. After its creation I ensure it works properly by loading it on IOS and get the typical "Welcome and open App.js". So far, so good. Then I wish to install, for example, a drawer component. So I go to JS.coach and choose a module I see fit(https://js.coach/react-native-drawer-layout?search=drawer&collection=React+Native). After this I do the very first thing it says to do, [image]

After running the NPM install its apparent it uninstalls about 700 packages and I assume this is where everything breaks. But I cannot figure out what to do past this or how to fix it. I have ran NPM install react-native after this and also have tried using the yarn package manager only for the same result. Is this due to my project setup or due to firewall settings within NPM? Either way I know it shouldn't be this hard to add a module, therefore, I know I must be majorly overlooking something. (I know the cmd screenshot uses a different package, just for show across different packages) [image]

What confused me however, is the fact that it seems to say there is an issue with the tunneler and it refusing to connect.

```
<!doctype html5>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">

        strong { font-weight: bold; }
        hr { -moz-box-sizing: content-box; box-sizing: content-box; height: 0; }
        html { font-family: sans-serif;   -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;   -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;   } body { margin: 0; }
        a { background-color: transparent; }
        a:active, a:hover { outline: 0; }
        </style>

        <style type="text/css">
            body { background-color: #f5f5f5; }
            .container { width: 500px; margin: auto; color: #444; padding: 5px; }
            a, strong { color: purple; text-decoration: none; }
            a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
            h2 { text-align: center; color: #000; }
            p { line-height: 20px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">


<h2>Failed to complete tunnel connection</h2>
<hr />
<p>
    The connection to <strong><a href="http://packager.ak-gj5.ae.rf-ink.exp.direct">http://packager.ak-gj5.ae.rf-ink.exp.direct</a></strong>
    was successfully tunneled to your ngrok client,
    but the client failed to establish a connection to
    the local address <strong><a href="http://localhost:19001">localhost:19001</a></strong>.
</p>
<p>
    Make sure that a web service is running on
    <strong><a href="http://localhost:19001">localhost:19001</a></strong> and that it is a valid address.
</p>
<p>
    The error encountered was: <strong style="color: #9E2929">dial tcp [::1]:19001: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.</strong>
</p>


        </div>
    </body>
</html>


ABI23_0_0RCTFBQuickPerformanceLoggerConfigureHooks
ABI24_0_0RCTFBQuickPerformanceLoggerConfigureHooks
<redacted>
<redacted>
<redacted>
<redacted>
<redacted>
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
UIApplicationMain
Exponent
<redacted>
```

Does anyone understand what I am doing wrong?

```
node -v
v8.9.3
npm -v
5.5.1
"expo": "^24.0.0",
"react": "16.0.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not going through Expo, but create a project that has both the iOS and Android projects.

Answer (score 0):

Use `yarn add` instead of `npm install`. I'm not 100% with react-native but creating React apps with create-react-app had similar issues and I got around that by using `yarn add`